# How to build a subdomain from script

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

In my project I have to make a subdomain, i.e

if the user name is XXX when he register, a sub domain will be created like XXX.example.com

how to do it?

I will use php for scripting.

Comment: Has been answered numerous times: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=create+subdomain+php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a script that seems to do exactly that, create a subdomain on your server on demand.
It probably needs a little bit of tweaking for it to work on your particular control panel,  but the review are quite positive as far as I can tell.

[Link](http://www.zubrag.com/downloads/cpanel_subdomains.zip)

Have you considered using htaccess and url rewriting?
Found this code that may help you:

```
# Rewrite <subdomain>.example.com/<path> to example.com/<subdomain>/<path>
#
# Skip rewrite if no hostname or if subdomain is www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# Extract (required) subdomain (%1), and first path element (%3), discard port number if present (%2)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}<>%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com(:80)?<>/([^/]*) [NC]
# Rewrite only when subdomain not equal to first path element (prevents mod_rewrite recursion)
RewriteCond %1<>%3 !^(.*)<>\1$ [NC]
# Rewrite to /subdomain/path
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/$1 [L]
```

[Source (Post #6)](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/1310.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little more complex than you think.

I suggest to do some reading on mod rewriting and htaccess.

You could start here:

[htaccess Tutorial](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/htaccess/)

[Modrewrite tutorial](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting#)

[Subdomain Modrewrite Example](http://www.easymodrewrite.com/example-subdomains)

**EDIT:** Or just go with one of the nice examples provided my fellow SO users. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As long as this is for non-SSL sites, then by far the easiest way is not to bother - just use a wildcard DNS domain and vhost, then map any domain specific behaviours in your PHP code. If you need SSL sites then its a lot more complicated - you need to have a seperate IP address/port for each certificate - and woldcard certs can be very expensive.

If you're wanting to set up some sort of hosting package then its a bit more involved - how you go about this depends on what webserver and DNS server you are using.

Assuming (again no SSL) with Apache on Unix/POSIX/Linux and bind, then, again I'd go with a wildcard DNS entry, then:
1) create a base dir for the website, optionally populate this with a default set of files
2) add a vhost definition in its own file in /etc/httpd/conf.d named as XXX.conf
3) send a kill -HUP to the HTTPD process (causes it to read the new config files without having to do a full restart).

One thing to note is that you really shouldn't allow the httpd process direct write access to its own config files - you definitely don't want to give it root privileges. A safer solution would be to create a CLI script to perform this using the username as an argument then make it setuid and invoke it from the script run by the HTTPD process.

C.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use a joker in your DNS server :

```
www.example.com.    IN  A   1.2.3.4
*.example.com.  IN  A   1.2.3.4
```

By this way, No subdomain has to be created : all are pointing to the same IP by default.

In your PHP code, you just have get $_SERVER["HOST"] and get the fist part :

```
$hostParts=explode('.',$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
$user=$hostParts[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure you have a wildcard domain setup in DNS, and make sure your webserver (apache?) directs all queries for that wildcard domain to your php file.

Then in php you can look at $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] to see which subdomain is used for that particular request.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will make sub-domains when an user registers.
Try this as .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [f]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}!^www.domain.com 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).domain.com 
RewriteRule ^$(.*) /$1/%1 [L]
```

make a function of a controller which will take the value of sub-domain and display what necessary.
like::

```
public function show ($domain)
{
  **.**..*..**.** Your code goes here
}
```

when a user will try this **xxx.domain.com/controller/show** this will be **domain.com/controller/show/xxx** . if you want to **xxx.domain.com** to be **domain.com/controller/show/xxx** just edit the htaccess file as you want.